# Possible to use list comprehension over iterable with different lengths?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to create a list via list comprehension which uses a [compound Boolean expression](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html#compound-boolean-expressions) which has at least one condition that assumes the existence of an index value from the underlying iterable's element (even if another condition doesn't and (should?) result in the expression being `True`)?

The interpreter throws `IndexError: tuple index out of range` when the code below is executed.

```
my_lst = [('30', ), ('30', '125'), ('30', '127'), ('30', '125', '567')]
[tpl for tpl in my_lst if (len(tpl) == 1 or tpl[2] == '125')]
# Desired result: [('30', ), ('30', '125'), ('30', '125', '567')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python indexes are 0-based.  Index `2` would retrieve the *third* item, not the second.

You want to access index `1` (the second item):

```
[tpl for tpl in my_lst if (len(tpl) == 1 or tpl[1] == '125')]
```

Comment: Wow. *Face in palm*. Sorry guys and gals. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: A tuple of len == 1 will throw the same error. Add a `len(tpl) == 2 && tpl[1] == 125`

Comment: @DavidK-J - If `len(tpl) == 1` returns `False`, then `tpl` must have more than one item and `tpl[1]` will work fine.  My code will only fail if there is an empty tuple.  But there is nothing to suggest that you could have an empty tuple from the OP's question.

Comment: If `len(tpl) == 1` returns false it could have 0 or 2+ elements, and will raise the same exception. Call it good practice/defensive programming.

Answer (score 1):

> Python indexes are 0-based. Index 2 would retrieve the third item, not the second.
>
> You want to access index 1 (the second item):
>
> [tpl for tpl in my_lst if (len(tpl) == 1 or tpl[1] == '125')]

This still has a potential bug. It is possible to have a zero length tuple, which would cause an error. This may not be a problem based on the rest of your code, but if it is you should use:

**Edited for excluding zero length tuples**

```
[tpl for tpl in my_lst if (len(tpl) != 0 and (len(tpl) == 1 or tpl[1] == '125'))]
```

Comment: This will return empty tuples?

Comment: I don't want the list comprehension to return empty tuples (which, in my application, shouldn't exist anyway).

Comment: It will. If this isn't desired then some other code would be needed. But this will prevent the index out of range error

Comment: Edited to exclude zero length tuples